# Socket connection through HTTP proxy with NTLM authenication

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy

I'm trying to build an application that would use TCP sockets to communicate with a server.

When a proxy is detected in system settings, the application tries to connect through it through these steps:

```
Connect to proxy.
Issue CONNECT Host:Port HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>
Issue <CR><LF>
```

However it turns out that the proxy also needs to do NTLM authentication using the credentials of current user who's logged in.

.Net already implement this using:

```
 Webproxy.crendentials = CredentialCache.GetDefaultCrendentials
```

But it only works with WebRequests types of sockets. And I am using regular sockets with Stream.Read and Stream.Write